# where is the tns entry for a user created in oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to know the tns entry of a user I created in Oracle 11g by ORACLE SYSTEM user.??????
TO connect it to a sql developer tools???

very mediocre question  but not able to find in google??

There are only these 3 entries in TNS.ora:

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1522))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl.168.1.6)
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: in the same tnsnames.ora file you're looking at.

Users reside in your database; you connected as `SYSTEM` to a database - I presume `ORCL` - and created a new user as

```
SQL> connect system/magicpwd@orcl
Connected.
SQL> create user new_user identified by pwd
  2  default tablespace users
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to new_user;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

In order to connect as a `new_user`, you use the same TNSNAMES.ORA database alias as you used for the `system` user - `orcl`:

```
SQL> connect new_user/pwd@orcl
Connected.
SQL>
```

All users in the same database share the same tnsnames.ora database alias; in your case, it is `orcl`. Later, when you acquire access to another databases, your tnsnames.ora file will get larger and larger (for example, I currently have access to 52 databases, so my tnsnames.ora has 52 entries in it) and you'll have to use those aliases when connecting to different users in different databases.

---

Though, note: each Oracle software product tends to create its own tnsnames.ora file. For example, if you created Oracle database, then Oracle Developer Suite (Forms & Reports), you'll have two tnsnames.ora files. In order to be able to connect to all your database using all those tools, you should keep tnsnames.ora files *synchronized*, i.e. all of them should be equal. That's a tedious job. In such cases, you'd create a `tns_admin` environment variable which points to one directory (folder) which contains a single tnsnames.ora copy, and you'd then maintain only that - one - file. TNS_ADMIN would take care that all Oracle software products use it.